# Modify (add white bar) to bulk jpg images in Image Magick

Tags: html

I am new here and a total novice (using Windows 8.1 with Image Magic) I have a folder (C:\users\rob\desktop\pics)that is full of jpg images (all 480x360). I want to put a white bar accross the bottom of all of these images. I believe the finished image will have to be slightly larger to accommodate this white bar. 480x380 should do it. The destination folder for the processed images is C:\users\rob\desktop\bar I have installed Image Magick and tested it (got the magician image) Code is totally new to me. Could somebody please show the code to type into cmd that will do what I am wanting (exactly what has to be typed and when to hit enter etc for a complete code dummy) Many thanks to anyone who can help Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a DOS commandline prompt:

On Windows 10, Open the Command Prompt window by clicking the Start button, then clicking All Programs, then clicking Accessories, and then clicking Command Prompt.

Go to your pics directory:

```
cd c:\users\rob\desktop\pics
```

Make yourself a 480x20 white bar as a separate image:

```
convert -size 480x20 xc:white whitebar.ppm
```

Append that to the bottom of each of your source images by running this command, still within your c:\users\rob\desktop\pics directory:

```
FOR %a in (*.jpg) DO convert %a whitebar.ppm -append ..\bar\%a
```

For more information, visit http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Comment: Thanks Glenn . As I said in my question I am totally new to Command Prompt and any of this (dummy)

Comment: See I can't even finish my message and I hit enter and it's gone. When you say "in your directory" I don't even know what to do.I know I have to type the code into the command promt window but how do I make it apply to the folder the pictures are in  /  Please help this dummy

Comment: Okay I worked it out now .Thanks for the help

Comment: To open command prompt in a folder simply hold the shift key and right click on the folder and select the option to open the command prompt there..Here is the code I used to get my white bar at bottom of my jpg files in bulk.(mogrify -background white -gravity north -extent 480x384 *.jpg). If you want to position the white bar differently change the "gravity" to center,south,east or west.Obviously change the extend dimensions to suit your picture sizing. Careful with Mognify back up your files first as it will change them all in your folder. Hope this helps somebody wanting to do this.